# How can you use the domain of the client connected over ssh in the shell?

Tags: ssh, shell, environment-variables

Is it possible to get the users ip address, domain name, or host-name of an established ssh connection in the shell? For example, when I connect over ssh the first printed line says something like this:

`Last Login: Sat Fri 17 19:00:00 2012 from some.website.net`

Is there an environment variable created or a way to access `some.website.net` or the ip address of the connected client. Preferably I would want `some.website.net`, but I might be able to make do with an ip address.

For your information, I plan to use this in order to automatically select the appropriate .tmux.conf file so that the statusline is less busy and can accommodate a smaller resolution screen i.e. a smartphone screen.

-- further details:

I am particularly interested in using this on an OSX computer, but it would be nice to have an OS independent solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what distribution you're on, so this might not apply to you. I use CentOS, which maintains a record in /var/log (your system probably has one, but it might be somewhere else).

Try:

```
cat /var/log/lastlog
```

Which returns (example):

```
2¤?Opts/05xxxxxxd7.bb.xxxxxx.com
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it will help in some instances such as OpenSUSE, which has this log (though it seems to spit out a lot of garbage, too), but I am currently interested in OSX which is a variant of BSD. Unfortunately, this is not a log file in OSX.

Comment: OSX records similar information to the lastlog file in the Apple Syslog. Check the files under `/var/log/asl` and see if you can find what you're looking for (I'm afraid I don't use OSX here).

Comment: thanks for that, but it seems these files are binary log files and are difficult to parse. Using `cat` spills a lot of junk to the screen and parsing it would be a pain, although they interestingly seem to have logs for each day of the past week. I'll investigate if there is a good way to use it.

Comment: Good luck, anyhow. What you need is in there somewhere ;)